# How to get only valid python package index

Tags: python, pip, package, package-info

As per https://pypi.org/simple/ we have 200,000 packages. I feel there are lot of packages found to be dummy/Experimental.
Where can we get the properly maintained package list for python?

If not, atleast please let me know what kind of strategy shoud I use to decide whether package is valid or not?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the package is valid"? There are packages that are not frequently released but still are useable and useful. And I'm sure there are packages that are maintained and frequently released but only interesting for their authors.

Comment: @phd aaaahorodatage, abc1,abc111,abc1234,abc12345,aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-aaaaaaaaa-aaaaaaasa-aaaaaaasa-aaaaasaa-aaaaaaasa-bbbbbbbbbbb at high level i see these packages looks has no meaning by its name. i would like to filter such packages.

Comment: Then the strategy should be something like this: evaluate the package name, assess its description, calculate how fresh the latest commit is, look at how frequent the releases come, verify its home page.